# Need suggestion for VS 2010 winform component

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, components

My goal is to create a C# winform application which has rounded panel, rounded button, and some more web-design-like components, such as this:

[image]

I already have Component One Studio .Net 2010 v3 but there's nothing I cant found there. Any suggestion? open-source / commercial is ok.

Comment: You should be using WPF.

Comment: Yep, WPF is the way to go, if You're looking for advanved gui options. Best components I've encountered for winforms was DevExpress

Comment: Hard to be heard over the WPF shouts these days.  Use the control's Region property to give it any shape you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used [3D Control Magic](http://www.multimediasoft.com/3dcm/) to implement Controls like you are wanting in Winforms.

[image]

[image]